# PowerPoint Linked Video's Path

Tags: video, microsoft-powerpoint

There is two way to insert a big file into powerpoint. Embedding and linking.
I have linked some videos in one of slides. I need to move my powerpoint into another PC, but it looks linking objects will work on source PC.

For example My linked video is here: "C:\Video\Target.mp4"
I extracted my powerpoint and searched xml files for the video path, but found nothing. I need to change the path of linked file. How it can be possible?

I even searched windows registry but nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior will depend on what version of PPT you're using.  In PPT 2010 and later, movies are embedded by default rather than linked.

If you're linking, the trick is to put the movie file in the same folder as the PowerPoint file, THEN add the movie to the presentation.

This will produce a link that points to just the file name of the video, not the complete path.

Then, so long as you keep the movie file and the PPT file in the same folder, the link should continue to work.

Comment: Nice Tip Steve: "the trick is to put the movie file in the same folder as the PowerPoint file, THEN add the movie to the presentation." Thank you, it solved my problem ;)

Answer (score 1):

As per official Microsoft website kb article you have to remove the link and re add in to the presentation by pointing the new video file location. Please refer the kb article for further details.

reference : http://office.microsoft.com/en-in/powerpoint-help/my-movie-doesn-t-play-HA010077716.aspx

Note : Check the fourth point

Comment: Please add (quote, or write in your own words) the relevant information here, not just with a link.